# 'Task<User>' does not contain a definition for 'LastActive'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Here's my .cs Code, where the error is being generated (line 23):'Task' does not contain a definition for 'LastActive' and no accessible extension method 'LastActive' accepting a first argument of type 'Task' could be found

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DatingApp.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using DatingApp.Models;
namespace DatingApp.Helper
{
    public class LogUserActivity : IAsyncActionFilter
    {
        public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            var resultContext = await next();

            var userId = int.Parse(resultContext.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);

            var repo = resultContext.HttpContext.RequestServices
                .GetService<IUserRepository>();

            var user = repo.GetUserById(userId);

            user.LastActive= DateTime.Now;
            await repo.SaveAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my repository

```
 public async Task<User> GetUserById(int id)
        {
            var user =await  _context.Users.Include(p=>p.Photos).FirstOrDefaultAsync(u=>u.Id==id);
            return user;
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`GetUserById` doesn't return a `User`, it returns a `Task<User>`.  You need to await it to get the `User`:

```
var user = await repo.GetUserById(userId);
```